# Hyperlinks in QTreeView

Tags: python, qt, hyperlink, pyqt, qtreeview

I'm trying to display clickable links within a QTreeView.  I've created my own QStyledItemDelegate, and I can draw text that looks like a link, but isn't clickable like a 
link would be.

One option I'm thinking of is creating a QLabel with a link, and drawing the QLabel inside the QTreeView cells.  The only problem is that I can't figure out how to add QLabels to the QTreeView.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out [QAbstractItemView::setIndexWidget](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget)?  You could create a QLabel like you said and pass it this function for the correct index.

Comment: Thanks!  I can't believe I missed this, I thought it was only available to QTreeWidgets.